# can't change image position with javascript function

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I did some code to change my image position

This code can run once , but doesn't work second time.

```
function prev() {
                    if(document.getElementById("bookCon").style.left=="0px"){}
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("bookCon").style.right-="800px";
                    }
                }
                function next() {
                    if(document.getElementById("bookCon").style.left=="5000px") {}
                    else { 
                        document.getElementById("bookCon").style.right+="800px";
                    }
                }
```

second edition ... also not work.

```
function getStyleNum(item,prop) {
            if (typeof item == "string") { item = document.getElementById(item); }
            return parseInt(item.style[prop],10);
        }
        function prev() {
            var item = document.getElementById("bookCon");
            if (getStyleNum(item,"right") !== 0) {
                var val = getStyleNum(item, "right");
                item.style.right = (val - 800) + "px";
            }
        }
        function next() {
            var item = document.getElementById("bookCon");
            if (getStyleNum(item,"right") !== 1600) {
                var val = getStyleNum(item, "right");
                item.style.right = (val + 800) + "px";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please describe the actual problem. It's probably due to the `+=` and `-=` operators! Convert the value first to an integer using `parseInt(var, 10)`, then add the "px" suffix and finally assign it to the CSS property.

Comment: JSFIDDLE WILL be great

Comment: function prev() {
    if(document.getElementById("bookCon").style.right=="0px"){}
    else {
     var x=(parstInt(document.getElementById("bookCon").style.right,10)-800).toString().concat("px");
     document.getElementById("bookCon").style.right=x;
    }
   }
   function next() {
    if(document.getElementById("bookCon").style.right=="5000px") {}
    else { 
     var x=(parstInt(document.getElementById("bookCon").style.right,10)+800).toString().concat("px");
     document.getElementById("bookCon").style.right=x;
    }
   }

this also not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. You can't do `+= "800px"` because you will end up with something like `"500px800px"` as these are strings.
2. You can't do math on strings.
3. You can't reliably compare to `"0px"`
4. You check the value of `.left` and set the value of `.right`.  You should only be using one or the other, not both.
5. Your code could a lot more DRY (not repeating things)
6. Reading the style property directly on the object won't include anything set via style sheets

If the `style.left` value is directly set on the object (and not initially coming from a style sheet) and your object is positioned, then you can use this type of logic (converting to numbers).  I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish by checking `.left` and then changing `.right` so this is just a guess at your logic, but you should be able to see the general idea of how you do this sort of thing.

```
function prev() {
    var item = document.getElementById("bookCon");
    if (parseInt(item.style.left, 10) != 0) {
        var val = parseInt(item.style.right, 10) || 0;
        item.style.right = (val - 800) + "px";
    }
}
```

You may find this util function useful:

```
function getStyleNum(item, prop) {
    if (typeof item == "string") {
        item = document.getElementById(item);
    }
    return parseInt(item.style[prop], 10) || 0;
}

function prev() {
    var item = document.getElementById("bookCon");
    if (getStyleNum(item, "left") != 0) {
        var val = getStyleNum(item, "right");
        item.style.right = (val - 800) + "px";
    }
}
```

P.S. I still don't understand why you would check the value of `.left` and then modify the value of `.right`.  Only one of these can be active at a given time.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/awjv9/

Comment: function prev() {
    var dd = document.getElementById("bookCon");
    var xx = parseInt(dd.style.right, 10);
    if(xx!=0) {
      item.style.right = (xx - 800) + "px";
    }
   }
   function next() {
    var dd = document.getElementById("bookCon");
    var xx = parseInt(dd.style.right, 10);
    if(xx!=1600) {
      dd.style.right = (xx + 800) + "px";
    }
   }

it's also not work...
(check left and change right is my false || sry )

Comment: @user2989188 - multi-line code in comments is completely unreadable.  You can use the edit button to add code to your answer and then add a comment to tell us what you added and why.

Comment: @user2989188 - I've updated my answer.  This carries out the logic described by your original code, but I don't know if that's what you're really trying to do as it makes no sense to be using both `.left` and `.right`.  The browser pays attention to one or the other, not both.

Comment: @user2989188 - it is possible that your object's style value does not have an initial value set on the object itself (not inherited from a style sheet).  See my working demo.  If you want to use the style sheet value, you have to obtain the property with [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) not by reading the property value directly.

Comment: @user2989188 - I would have to see your exact code and HTML to know why you're getting `NaN`.  You can check for that in `getStyleNum()` with [`isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) if you want and return `0` in that case.

Comment: @user2989188 - I've amended my `getStyleNum()` function so it will return `0` instead of `NaN` if there is no style set.